# Is Liszt really pronounced like the English word "list"?

Tags: pronunciation

I would think Franz Liszt's surname would be pronounced "least" or "leasht," but according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgmjdL1OGKo), it is pronounced "list." Is that true? If so, why?

Comment: Not related to German language.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The name is pronounced as the German word "List" which comes very close to the English word "list".

To understand it, you have to know that Franz Liszt was an Austrian-Hungarian composer. In Hungarian his name is *Liszt Ferenc*. In Hungarian "sz" is pronounced similarly as the German "ß", and in fact in former times the modern German letter "ß" was written as "sz". And up to now in "ß" is pronounced as "s - z" ("ess- tsett") when one pronounces the individual letters.

His father was Adam Liszt whose name is also spelled as *Adam List* which is of German origin. His professional career took place in the Kingdom of Hungary (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Liszt)) which was part of the Austrian empire. In Hungarian the letter "s" is pronounced as the English "sh", and this explains the spelling with "sz": Adam Liszt wanted his name to be pronounced *reasonably correctly*.

Here you can listen to the [German pronunciation](https://de.howtopronounce.com/german/franz-liszt) and [Hungarian pronunciation](https://de.forvo.com/word/ferenc_liszt/).

Comment: How about the vowel? OP guessed it should be 'ee' not 't**i**n"

Comment: @theonlygusti: I think "least" would be spelled *liest* in German. That's actually a word, the third person singular of *lesen*.

Comment: _pronounced similarly as the German "ß"_: Why complicate things? Hungarian _sz_ and German _ß_ are both pronounced identically to English _s_.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, true. It's a name. It's pronounced as the person who bears it wants to see it pronounced.

Further, it follows the usual way a 'i' is pronounced in German when followed by a consonant: short like the 'i' in the English 'list'. The sz is a rare and antique way to denote the ß character when the ß is not available - but the ß actually is a ligature letter for the combination sz - either way, it is pronounced as the 's' in the English 'list', too.

Comment: The _sz_ in Liszt's name is _not_ an alternative way of denoting _ß_, but stemming from Hungarian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz_(digraph)#Hungarian

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach In this special case, it's rather a *Hungarian transcription* of the German name "List" (That Liszt's father brought to Hungary).

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach if you look up the history of how the letter ß came into being: it *is* a ligature. Hence also its name. The fact that in modern German you may not replace an ß wit sz anymore does not change history. Also the actual choice of List to change the spelling of his name to keep its pronounciation in a predominantly Hungarian society does not change pronounciation rules - and that's all I elaborate on.

Answer (score 4):

"Least" and "list" are good approximations, because the vowel in Liszt sounds similar to the one in "least" but it is short like the one in "list".

least /liːst/

list /lɪst/

Liszt /list/

Comment: "least" has a long i, but Franz Liszt is pronounced with a short i. At least for me as a German, the two do not sound very similar.

Comment: @Jan I've always heard it pronounced with a long i. That's however mainly by Austrians...

Comment: @jwenting this guy pronounces Liszt with a short i (about 48 seconds into the podcast). But then he is probably not Austrian.

Comment: The Hungarian pronunciation is exactly as @g.kertesz says: it is a _short_ vowel, but with the quality of the English _long_ vowel in _least_. Scots English pronounces _least_ this way. (By the way, _liszt_ means _flour_ in Hungarian; but this is not the origin of the name _Liszt_.)

Comment: @jwenting: I am Austrian and I am dealing a lot with classical music (I am singing in a [well known Austrian concert choir](https://www.wienersingakademie.at/)). I never ever have heard someone pronounce the name *Liszt* with a long [iː]. This would make no sense, because in German two or more consonants at the end of a syllable always indicate a short pronunciation of the vowel before, also in Austrian German. (Exceptions exist but are rare.) I only have heard a boy (a member of [Wiener Sängerknaben](http://www.wsk.at)) who pronounced s and z separately ([lɪst͡st]) before he was corrected.